# Does Android keep logs of MTP connections it made?

Tags: android, mtp

Does Android keep logs of MTP connections it made? What info (if any) does it log of the device it wss logged to (say, computer host name, MAC address, etc) and how can I access this log?

Answer (score 0):

**Configure On-Device Developer Options**
Tap Select USB Configuration to specify how you want the computer to identify the device. Configure devices for charging only, to transfer files (MTP), to transfer pictures (PTP), to use your mobile internet on the PC (RNDIS), or to transfer audio or MIDI files.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html#debugging

**Logcat Command-line Tool**
In this document
Command-line syntax
Filtering log output
Control log output format
Format modifiers
Viewing alternative log output buffers
Logging from code
 Logcat is a command-line tool that dumps a log of system messages, including stack traces when the device throws an error and messages that you have written from your app with the Log class.

This page is about the command-line logcat tool, but you can also view log messages from the Logcat window in Android Studio. For information about viewing and filtering logs from Android Studio, see Write and View Logs with Logcat.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-logcat

Comment: That wasn't my question